# NullPointerException ao remover elemento da pilha

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tentando implementar uma estrutura de pilha em Java, mas quando tento remover um elemento recebo o seguinte erro:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.magnoliamedeiros.pilhafila.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:17)
    at br.com.magnoliamedeiros.pilhafila.Pilha.pop(Pilha.java:13)
    at br.com.magnoliamedeiros.pilhafila.Program.main(Program.java:22)
```

Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo? (as linhas do erro estão marcadas nos trechos de código)

Meu programa:

```
//...
Pilha<String> pilha = new Pilha<String>();          
//...
pilha.push("Márcia");
pilha.pop(); // LINHA #22
```

Classe `Pilha`:

```
public class Pilha<T> extends LinkedList<T>{        
    public void push(T valor){
        add(valor);
    }

    public T pop() throws Exception{
        if(isEmpty()){
            throw new Exception("Pilha vazia!");
        }
        return this.remove(0); // LINHA #13
    }
}
```

Classe `Node`:

```
public class Node<T> {
    Node<T> proximo;
    Node<T> anterior;
    T valor;

    public void setProximo(Node<T> proximo){
        this.proximo = proximo;
    }

    public Node<T> getProximo(){
        return proximo;
    }

    public void setAnterior(Node<T> anterior){
        this.anterior = anterior;
    }

    public Node<T> getAnterior(){
        return anterior;
    }

    public void setValor(T valor){
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public T getValor(){
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Classe `LinkedList`:

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements java.util.List<T>{
    Node<T> inicio;
    Node<T> fim;
    int size = 0;

    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        if(index==0){
                inicio.getAnterior().setProximo(inicio.getProximo()); // LINHA #17
                inicio.getProximo().setAnterior(inicio.getAnterior());
                inicio.setAnterior(null);
                inicio.setProximo(null);
                return inicio.getValor();
        }else{
            int i = 1;
            while(i!=this.size()){
                i++;
                inicio.setProximo(inicio.getProximo());

                if(i == index){
                    inicio.getAnterior().setProximo(inicio.getProximo());
                    inicio.getProximo().setAnterior(inicio.getAnterior());
                    inicio.setAnterior(null);
                    inicio.setProximo(null);
                    return inicio.getValor();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public boolean add(T e){
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>();
        newNode.setValor(e);

        if(inicio == null){
            inicio = newNode;
        }
        if(fim == null){
            fim = newNode;
        }else{
            fim.setProximo(newNode);
            newNode.setAnterior(fim);
            fim = newNode;
        }
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size==0;
    }

}
```

Comment: a pergunta tinha muito código e fica difícil pra qualquer um conseguir seguir o que está acontecendo. Tentei dar uma limpada, mantendo só as partes relevantes pra execução do erro (retirando, por exemplo o que tinha a ver com a fila). Espero ter ajudado. Além disso, tenho quase certeza de que o problema é a referência a `inicio.getAnterior` em `LinkedList.remove`, sem que `inicio` tenha um valor. Infelizmente não uso Java a anos e não posso confirmar, nem sugerir uma solução, mas outros podem. Se quiser, [mcve] pode te ajudar a criar exemplos menores e mais práticos pra postar aqui

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda na pergunta @Gabe

Comment: Duas perguntas: **1.** A exception não traz mais mensagens além das que foram postadas? **2.** A pilha tem elementos?

Comment: @jbueno A exception e o código inteiro do programa estão na [edição anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/170953/2). Pelo que vi, essa é a única mensagem de exceção e a pilha tem 3 elementos antes do primeiro `pop`

Comment: Pois é @Gabe. Esse pode ser o *trace* completo, mas acho que a *exception* traz consigo alguma mensagem. Suponho que seja um `NullPointerException` em algum dos métodos encadeados naquela linha, mas, a essa altura do dia (são 21h aqui) é um pouco difícil de ler o código racionalmente. Ainda mais com tanto tempo longe do Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considere o trecho:

```
if(index==0){
                inicio.getAnterior().setProximo(inicio.getProximo()); // LINHA #17
```

Neste caso, o `NullPointerExeption` (NPE) ocorreu porque se `index` é zero, então não há nenhum objeto antes e `inicio.getAnterior()` vai retornar `null`.

As regras para gerenciar uma lista ligada, incluem nunca acessar o elemento anterior ao primeiro, nem o posterior ao último. É importante também considerar que se um elemento é o único na lista, ele é o primeiro e o último ao mesmo tempo.

No caso, remover o primeiro elemento, é tão simples quanto fazer o `inicio` da lista apontar para o próximo elemento. Se a lista não estiver vazia, é claro. Se a lista contém apenas um elemento, o início vai apontar para `null`, portanto tem que considerar isto no código e nunca assumir que vai existir algum valor na variável.

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu...